# Imported photo gallery can't be loaded in the browser (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made an photo gallery in javascript.
But it failed to load into my HTML website.
Only a blank block that I created have appear in the middle of the page.

Can anybody helped to see where's the problem. I have look for the bugs for a few days already. Here is my code. I will attached my full coding in the following link: [My Full Code](https://codepen.io/davidchan0629/pen/MOBwmG)

```
<!-- Import photoAlbum -->
<link href="css/blueberry.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="vendor/blueberry/jquery.blueberry.js"></script>
<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.blueberry').blueberry();
  });
  </script>
```

```
<section class ="bg-primary">
<div class="blueberry">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide3.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://marktyrrell.com/labs/blueberry/img/slide4.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: open console and see for errors if there are any

Comment: If you have errors in the console, please post them. Also, post a screenshot of the current result. I link to a live page would also be helpful if possible.

Comment: it is 100% your errors and scripts that you load before the gallery. Gallery itself works fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOBJMq

Comment: Your codepen is full of errors, press F12 and see the console, see the network tab and how many css files and js files fail to load. You also load jquery multiple times, once is enough.